# string to snake_case function javascript

Tags: javascript

very new to javascript here, trained about 3 month in python, im a new software development student and finding the syntax of javascript very hard compared to python, i really need help with this question as i have a new teach this semester who hasnt taught us javascript functions very well and ive been trying my best to get ahead of the curve with personal research and signing up to Udemy etc but im completely stumped on alot of questions on this newest Quantitive Assesment ive recently gotten and if someone could point me in the right direction on this one itd be greatly appreciated!

Problem 1: replace all internal whitespace in a string value with underscore ('_'), and makes it lowercase.

We want to be able to convert a string to Lower Snake Case style, so that all leading/trailing whitespace is removed, and any internal spaces, tabs, or dots, are converted to '_' and all letters are lower cased.

The snake() function should work like this:

- snake('abc') --> returns 'abc'
- snake(' ABC ') --> returns 'abc'
- snake('ABC') --> returns 'abc'
- snake('A BC') --> returns 'a_bc'
- snake(' A bC  ') --> returns 'a-bc'
- snake('A   BC') --> returns 'a_bc'
- snake('A.BC') --> returns 'a_bc'
- snake(' A..  B   C ') --> returns 'a_b_c'

heres what i tried but doesn't work so well :

```
function snakeCase(str) {
  var result = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1");
  return result.split(" ").join("_").toLowerCase();
}

console.log(snakeCase("abc"));
```

Comment: Google for function split() and functions to lower string case

Comment: Post some code to show what you have tried. It is not a good way to learn to just ask for the answers at SO.

Comment: Why are there `-` in the results?

Comment: I tried a couple if statements but my teacher only taught us for one hour on this concept so my experience is limited but I'll post my attempt from now thank you guys for the help

Comment: If you're going to just dump-paste an exercise, please instead [read the posting guidelines and follow them](/help/how-to-ask) and use proper [markdown](/markdown) in your post. And then on a modern JS note: don't use `var`, use `let` for variables that should be reassignable, and `const` for variables whose value should be fixed. `var` is a legacy keyword for function-scoped, rather than block-scoped, variable declaration.

Comment: @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans give me a break , be kind , this is my first post on here im just learning here ok, like anything I'll learn as time goes on unless i keep getting complaints on this singular post then I won't be able to post anything else, obviously if I was taught properly there wouldn't be the mistakes im making here right? And also I was taught to use var on variables and that's all I know right now

Answer (score 0):

trim, lowercase, regexp to replace whitespaces (and dots) with _. should work

```js
function snake(str) {
  str = str.trim();
  str = str.replace(/[\s\.]+/g, '_');
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  return str;

}

console.log(snake('abc'))
console.log(snake(' ABC '))
console.log(snake('ABC'))
console.log(snake('A BC'))
console.log(snake(' A bC '))
console.log(snake('A BC'))
console.log(snake('A.BC'))
console.log(snake(' A.. B C '))
```

Comment: yes , but he wants to have `-` s and `_`s

Comment: how exactly? I think that was a typo.  btw `-` is called kebab-case